# Serialize multiple CakePHP formhelper forms for ajax post

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp

I have a situation where I have been handed an already built user interface that contains a tabbed view where each tab contains a form generated using the CakePHP formhelper.  Each of these forms has it's own id and the former developer daisy chained ajax requests for each form on a single submit.

The client still wants all forms to post simultaneously so I was hoping I could serialize multiple forms like this:

```
var post_data = $("#form-1, #form-2").serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/places/save_form",
    data: post_data,
    success: function(result) {},
    error: function(result) {}
});
```

However, in the end point where it posts to I seem to get an empty array from $this->request->data; whereas that returned all my form values when I was serializing a single form.

I also don't get anything in the $_POST once in the controller so it seems like it is being scrubbed before it gets there.

Is there any way to get multiple formhelper forms into a single ajax post and then deal with saving them on the other end?

Comment: you can use cakephp js helper 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html

Comment: @AlimonKarim - I'm on CakePHP 3 and it says that has been removed.  Was there something specific in there that you found that could accommodate multiple forms in a single ajax request?

Comment: How about changing `data: post_data,` to `data: dataString,` ?

Comment: Sorry for the inaccuracy in my code snippet.  I double checked my code and I am using the same var in both places.  I just screwed up when pasting the snippet in at two different times.  I have updated the snippet here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this working like this:

```
var post_data = { };
post_data.FormOne = $("#form-1").serialize();
post_data.FormTwo = $("#form-2").serialize();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/places/save_form",
    data: post_data,
    success: function(result) {
        $(loading_div).remove();
    },
    error: function(result) {
        $(loading_div).remove();
    }
});
```

On the controller side:

```
public function save_form() {
    $FormOne = $this->request->data['FormOne'];
    $FormOneValues = array();
    parse_str($FormOne, $FormOneValues);

    $FormTwo = $this->request->data['FormTwo'];
    $FormTwoValues = array();
    parse_str($FormTwo, $FormTwoValues);

    echo '<pre>'; 
    print_r($FormOneValues);
    print_r($FormTwoValues);
    die();
}
```

My issues seemed to have as much to do with getting the request formatted correctly on the js end as it did with getting access to it on the CakePHP controller end.